# Why the Video is not fullscreen in VideoPlayer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-video-player

I  copied and pasted the example of the [VideoPlayer package](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) but on the web is not full screen, how can I solve this.

**Example Code**

```dart
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-womans-hands-decorating-a-handmade-soap-2803-large.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..play()
      ..setLooping(true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

**OutPut**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a stack widget and it solved the issue.
Based on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0ZNQ0YXyfE

Answer (score 1):

If you check `_controller.value.aspectRatio,`, the `value` is coming from video.

Video is playing based on its `aspectRatio`, not screen's aspect ratio.

I am using `LayoutBuilder` to get screen size, you also use `MediaQuery`.
In this case `homme:`  will be like

```dart
 home: Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: constraints.maxWidth / constraints.maxHeight,
                  // _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
      ),
```

**Result**

[image]

> is you are thinking about Top and bottom spaces here, is empty because of it is beyond video aspectRatio.

Comment: Hi mate. Thank you for the help, but now don't show the video at all. is there a problem with this line    aspect ratio: constraints.maxWidth / constraints.maxHeight,   ?

Comment: what's the errors?  Did you use `LayoutBuilder` just like me, pasted or typed?

Comment: Actually, there is no error. I copied the pasted, but now just show a white page. No video

Comment: it might be on loading state, do `flutter clean` and run again, and white screen because of `:Container`

Comment: Exactly , Let me do the flutter clean

Comment: hi, Mate it didn't work!

Comment: What's the current state of your output

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for full-screen mode in flutter web.

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
```

For exit, the full-screen use the below.

```
document.exitFullscreen();
```

You have to must import `import 'dart:html';`